# What is {...props} and how to get my function from other

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to learn react native and especially react navigation v5.

According to this topic: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/themes/#using-the-current-theme-in-your-own-components, I try to make a dark mode but I don't understand how to call my `toggleTheme()` function in the `TouchableRipple`.

My App.js :

```js
const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = React.useState(false);

const theme = isDarkTheme ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme;

function toggleTheme() {
    setIsDarkTheme(isDark => !isDark);
}

return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
            <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
                    //{...other things...}
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
);
```

My DrawerContent.js :

```js
export function DrawerContent(props) {
    const paperTheme = useTheme();

    //{...other things...}

    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        //{...other things...}
        <Drawer.Section title="Préférences">
                <TouchableRipple onPress={props.toggleTheme}>
                    <View style={styles.preferences}>
                        <Text>Dark Theme</Text>
                        <View pointerEvents="none">
                            <Switch value={paperTheme.dark} />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableRipple>
    //{...other things...}
```

Accoding to the topic, If I call `onPress={props.toggleTheme}` the darktheme will appear, but this is not working, So how to call this function from App.js in DrawerContent.js

The toggle is moving if I set `<Switch value={!paperTheme.dark}` so `useTheme();` seems to be working.

And last question, what is `{...props}`, I can't log it because he return out of memory.

Thanks for people who can help me to understand this!

Comment: I'll answer your last question about `{...props}`. This is basically passing ALL props received in this component to another component. So in your example, all the `props` received by your `DrawerContent` component are being passed to your `DrawerContentScrollView`.

Comment: to extend on what @James has said - the props being passed into DrawerContent are the props passed into the current component, which don't contain the current components function: toggleTheme.  you can pass this, additional prop in a couple of ways, but the simplest way would be to just add it to: `<DrawerContent {...props} />` e.g. `<DrawerContent {...props} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />` it will then appear as a function reference in the props of DrawerContent  as props.toggleTheme - additionally - you may need to bind this function in the parent, to maintain its scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to: 
`<DrawerContent {...props} />`

e.g. 
`<DrawerContent {...props} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />`

it will then appear as a function reference in the props of `DrawerContent` as `props.toggleTheme`

```
const [isDarkTheme, setIsDarkTheme] = React.useState(false);

const theme = isDarkTheme ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme;

function toggleTheme() {
    setIsDarkTheme(isDark => !isDark);
}

return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
            <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />}>
                    //{...other things...}
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    </PaperProvider>
);
```